# Error Running Code Analysis in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, oauth, code-analysis

I receive the following two errors when I try to compile my MVC4 web project:

> CA0058    Error Running Code Analysis CA0058 : The referenced assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' could not be found. This assembly is required for analysis and was referenced by: C:\Users\bflynn\Visual Studio Sites\mnp\bin\mnp.dll, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll. [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)

and

> CA0001 Error Running Code Analysis CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246.  [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)

I recently added the `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet` package to the application, and it seems tied to that.  I have Cleaned, Rebuilt, Open/Closed the program, Uninstalled/Re-installed the package, yet the errors persists.

Comment: have you check the references in your project ?

Comment: Yep - nothing missing.  And like I mentioned, I have removed and reinstalled the packages/references a couple times. no luck :(

Comment: I was just typing the same question.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this too.

Don't upgrade DOA to 4.1

It looks like the aspnet dll has a specific version referenced. Altough it's .nuspec file says 4.0+ is ok...

Solution:

Uninstall-Package -Force each DotNetOpenAuth package (core /aspnet /oauth/openid etc)

Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet -Version 4.0.4.12182

Comment: Uninstall-Package dotnetopenauth –RemoveDependencies is a faster way

Answer (score 5):

I used this to resolve the issue:

```
1. Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth –RemoveDependencies
2. Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet -Version 4.0.4.12182
3. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue the other day and reported it http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/443

Answer (score 0):

Problem was reported on 21. september 2012. (http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/443)

It was closed on 5. june 2013 with message:

> The next version of MVC will not have a dependency on DotNetOpenAuth. Use the recommended workarounds below.

So I used the workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/12847018/1016682

Answer (score 0):

[Code Analysis error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0 in MVC4 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120741/code-analysis-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-2/12847018#12847018)

See Yao's answer.  The only solution I found that actually works for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Though the code analysis issue got fixed, the web application wouldn't run because of the following error.

**Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

It turned that the web.config was not cleaned as part of the uninstall. 
I had to remove the following dependentAssembly from web.config under the runtime/assemblyBinding  section.

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

The details can be read in http://www.bigcode.net/2013/07/error-running-code-analysis-in-vs2012.html