# Using Microsoft.Bcl.Async with Code Analysis causes errors

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop, base-class-library

I'm trying to use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) and Code Analysis, but when I run Code Analysis I get one or more errors.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Update 2.

This is easy for me to reproduce:

1. Create a new default Console App that targets `.Net 4`.
2. Right click `References` then select `Manage NuGet Packages...`
3. Click `Online` and type `async` into the `Search Online` box.
4. You should see `Async for .Net Framework 4 ...`. Click `Install` and accept all questions.
5. Add to `Main()` a line that says: `TaskEx.Delay(1000);` and a `using System.Threading.Tasks;`
6. Go to project properties, Code Analysis section and tick `Enable Code Analysis on Build`.
7. Compile the program.

I get two Code Analysis errors:

> CA0052 Error Running Code Analysis CA0052 : No targets were selected.  [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)
>
> CA0055 Error Running Code Analysis CA0055 : Could not load ConsoleApplication2.exe. The following error was encountered while reading module 'ConsoleApplication2': Could not resolve member reference: [Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx::Delay.   [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)

I get *different* code analysis errors for other test programs. A basic Windows Forms app I tried gives me:

> CA0001 Error Running Code Analysis CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'AsyncForNet4': Could not resolve member reference: [Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx::Delay.  [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)

Two questions:

1. Can anyone else reproduce this problem?
2. Does anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As mentioned by Nicole, this occurs because Code Analysis/FxCop is enforcing that strong names including versions match exactly. This behavior makes sense for .NET Framework, *until* you start to factor in binding redirects (or other platforms such as Store, Phone & Silverlight which always allow later versions of an assembly to match an earlier version), which FxCop does not respect.

I wrote this original behavior in FxCop, and it was over optimizing for correctness vs real world. At the time, we didn't have an opt out other than via the App.Config. However, luckily after I left the team, some smart person on the team added one both via the command-line and within Visual Studio.

**Via the command-line:**

```
FxCopCmd.exe /assemblycomparemode:StrongNameIgnoringVersion ...
```

**Via Visual Studio:**

1. Right-click on the project in **Solution Explorer** and choose
   **Unload**
2. Right-click on the project in **Solution Explorer** and choose **Edit**
3. Within  the first `<PropertyGroup>` element, add the following:    `<CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions> /assemblycomparemode:StrongNameIgnoringVersion</CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions>`
4. Right-click on the project in **Solution Explorer**, choose **Reload** saving the changes when prompted.

**This will only work in Visual Studio 2012 and higher.**

Comment: Did you test it in VS2013? How would you know it will keep on working?

Comment: This also works in VS2013, and will continue working for the foreseeable future.

Comment: I can't imagine a question that relates to Portable Class Libraries answered by David Kean that doesn't earn a checkmark. The saying goes *"straight out of the horse's mouth."*

Comment: What about not using VS to compile the solution? I'm using MSBuild in the CI server (TeamCity) and I have CodeAnalysis enabled. I've added the mentioned line to csproj file but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the versions of the dependencies declared in Bcl.Async assemblies don't match those available at analysis time.  The simplest workaround is to adjust FxCop's `AssemblyReferenceResolveMode` as described at http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/06/14/reference-resolutions-changes-in-code-analysis-and-fxcop-part-2.aspx.

Comment: note that link/site seems to be dead there is an archived copy at http://web.archive.org/web/20130328002543/http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/06/14/reference-resolutions-changes-in-code-analysis-and-fxcop-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, and looking for a solution.  The only mention I've found is in the comments of the bcl blog post - [Microsoft.Bcl.Async is Now Stable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx) (page 3 of comments) where Immo Landwerth's response to someone having the same issue is;

> We're looking into it. At first glance it seems like a unification issue in the VS static code analysis feature (FxCop). We've contacted the owners of it. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a workaround other than disabling code analysis for those projects :-(

The response is dated 26th April 2013, whether there have been any developments since then.

So for now I guess the workarounds are:

- Disable code analysis
- Rewrite your code not to use `TaskEx.Delay()`