# strange compilation error vs 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

The error

```
Error   102 Code Analysis detected errors.  See Code Analysis results window or log file for details.   KickOffTitan
```

Code Analysis results window

```
CA0001  Error Running Code Analysis 
CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'KickOffTitan':
Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid.   
[Errors and Warnings]   (Global)
```

I have some inkling that this might have to do with using vs2012 + .net 4.0 + `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`

If I remove async/await but leave in TaskEx

I get many     Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid and 1

```
CA0001  Error Running Code Analysis CA0001 : Could not resolve reference to System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)
```

If i remove any stuff from async package(async/await/TaskEx) it compiles

Comment: Could you provide detailed error and sample code?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245246%28v=vs.80%29.aspx - "For more diagnostic information, view the CodeAnalysisReport.xml in the \obj folder."

Comment: it doesn't tell me about any report file, there doesn't seem to be any xml files in the obj folder

Comment: That seems to be it error wise

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Microsoft.Bcl.Async with Code Analysis causes errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298281/using-microsoft-bcl-async-with-code-analysis-causes-errors)