# Code Analysis VS2012 - Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, fxcop

I am getting an error when running Code Analysis on a VS2012 solution (C#). I have 43 projects in this solution but 4 are failing with the following error:

```
CA0001  Error Running Code Analysis
CA0001 : Rule=Microsoft.Security#CA2122, 
Target=Modules.Inspirations.Data.InspirationRepository.#AddImage(Modules.Inspirations.Models.InspirationImage) : 
The following error was encountered while reading module 'Modules.Inspirations': 
Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid.   
[Errors and Warnings]   
(Global)
```

The only thing I can think of is that there maybe an issue with the method parameter being a complex type (or something askew with the complex type itself). However, there are plenty of other methods that take a complex type as a parameter and the Code Analysis tool has no problems with those.

There seems to be no more detail available then the error message above. I've done a search for this but nothing has come up that fixes this issue.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft.Bcl.Async? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298281/using-microsoft-bcl-async-with-code-analysis-causes-errors

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to get more information from the Code Analysis run because of the way the exception is handled internally.  To dig deeper, you would need to try attaching a debugger to the `fxcopcmd.exe` process to see why the type signature seems to be unparseable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this error hides the actual error which is actually a warning!
This warning is CA0060: "The indirectly-referenced assembly xxxx could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete."

In that case, a correction consists in copying the assembly in the output dir (ex: bin\debug). Using the copy local = true property for referenced assembly is one way to do so.