# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I am developing Web Application to upload a file on Google Drive but, there is a runtime exception as :- **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)** 
I don't have any idea about this Please help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following approach:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager console
3. Run the following command:

*PM>Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async*

Comment: I am working with Visual studio 2010 and Couldn't find  Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager console

Comment: katherine heigl Please tell me what can I do now?

Comment: 1.From the tools -> extension manager download : NuGet package manager
2.From the Visual studio 2010 go to Tools –> Library Package Manager –> Package manager console
Also on the following link you can find information how to instal NuGet: [link] (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget#Installing_NuGet)

Comment: I did it and again I run the application now it's giving me another exception somewhat like previous one as :- Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: The same problem is resolved in following thread: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431975/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-2-0-0-0-in-mvc4-web-ap)

Comment: Additionally, I needed to copy the *.exe.config file from the build folder into the solution folder. Otherwise, the .dlls could not be referenced.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 it is Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console