# Dll hell when deploying ASP MVC4 application to Windows 2003 with IIS6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm struggling to have my application working after deploy to Windows 2003 server. After some investigation it seems that I have a problem with the way application is build/published or configured. This is what happens:

- on my developers machine I have a MVC4 project (targets .NET 4 and ASP .NET 4). Everything runs smoothly. I have many NuGet packages referenced by the project. And one of them is

> packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.15\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll

- after deploying the application to Windows 2003 server, and (I hope) properly configuring IIS etc I get the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

And I don't know what is happening. I've checked bin folder on the server and I can see **System.Net.Http.dll** dll with version **2.2.15**. So why application is trying to load **System.Net.Http.dll** with version **2.0.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the System.Net.Http.dll it's based on .Net 4.5 that's not supported on Windows 2003 and 2003 R2 (as crazy as it sounds)

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2723735-make-net-4-5-work-on-any-os-that-supports-4-0

Check out your dependencies and remove System.Net.Http.dll if you can or, since 4.5 it's an inplace replacement for 4.0 maybe you will need to remove 4.5 from your dev environment

Check out this other SO question: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0 in MVC4 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431975/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-2-0-0-0-in-mvc4-web-ap)

Comment: The package in question has a `net40` and a `net45` directory, so it should be a .NET 4.0 library.

Comment: Target framework of all my project in the application is 4 - so I guess this is not the case

Comment: Yes, I know, but some DLLs targets 4.5 (since it's an inplace upgrade)

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. I'll investigate it.