# Could not load file or assembly "System.net.http" Strange Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, .net-assembly

Having a very strange issue and I'm not sure what is causing the problem.

Basic Background is - I have an Umbraco website running on a development server, using asp 4.0(Integrated Pipeline) which worked fine. No compiler errors or anything.

Today we have moved the site to our live server, we had given it its own dedicated application pool which is also using Asp 4.0 (Integrated) identical to the previous server. Yet I am now running into a FileNotFoundException. (See below)

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
```

*I Dont know if the application pool is directly related but thought I would post this information anyway incase it may help*

The site has always referenced the V2.0.0.0 of System.Net.Http, yet on the swap it seems to have lost that reference in some way.

*Side Note* : I Have researched through other stack overflow questions that have similar issues with the System.net.http assembly. But I could not find an issue that related to the moving of a website breaking the dependancy.

Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: Are both your server 32bit?

Comment: Have you checked the [umbracoRoot]\'bin' directory on the live web server? e.g. comparing it against your dev environment?

Comment: Does the live server also have ASP.NET 2.0/3.5 installed?

Comment: @NicolasR Both servers are 64bit as it stands.

Comment: @ne1410s I have checked the bin folder and both do contain the System.Net.Http dll with identical public keys and version references. (Also checked the web.config to confirm they were referencing the same assembly).

Comment: @Luaan Just had a check on Programs and features - From what I can see only .Net Framework 4 is Installed. Would you advise installing 2.0 and 3.5 aswell?

Comment: @Chancerson Yeah, .NET 4.0 does not contain .NET 2.0, and you're referencing .NET 2.0 libraries. So install .NET 3.5 (which does contain 2.0 as well) and you should be fine. Oh, and I don't think you should have those binaries in the `bin` folder of your application - they should be taken from the GAC.

Comment: @Luaan Cracking, Ill give that a go. Cheers for the pointers guys, I shall report back if any more issues arise!

Comment: If you're using MVC, it may be worth checking the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431975/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-2-0-0-0-in-mvc4-web-ap